# Add web service and WCF request and response body in Application Insight

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, azure-application-insights

i have to customize the dependency telemetry and add web service and WCF Request and response body.

i written code to customize telemetry, but not sure how to log request/response body

```
public class ApplicationInsightsDependencyInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {

            var dependency = telemetry as DependencyTelemetry;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dependency?.Type))
            {
                if (dependency.Type.Contains("Service") || dependency.Type.ToLower().Contains("http"))
                {
                    var request = new object();
                    var response = new object();
                    var responseHeaders = new object();
                    dependency.TryGetOperationDetail("HttpRequest", out request);
                    dependency.TryGetOperationDetail("HttpResponse", out response);
                    dependency.TryGetOperationDetail("HttpResponseHeaders", out responseHeaders);



                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone please let me know how to log request/response body.